# Elements in a layout not resizing according to weights as they should

Tags: android, android-layout

In the layout below, `EditText` (blue background color) is not visible, it has 0 width and the spinner takes all the space. Why?

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/Label.Plain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="@string/Distance" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_hfDistance"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0000ff"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/spinner_text" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sp_hfDistanceUnits"
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="#ff00ff00"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you set up the parent `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`, and similar width for the two children, weights are taken into account by their inverse.

```
real weight = (1/weight) / sum((1/weight) for weight in the layout)
```

Therefore, the real weight of the EditText is 1, whereas the real weight of the spinner is 1/0 = infinite. By comparison, the EditText is not visible anymore and the spinner takes all the space.

To change this behavior, change both for the spinner and the EditText `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: What's the difference between `0dp` and `fill_parent`?

Comment: This is not a very good explanation, since the weights are not very relevant when the widths are `fill_parent`. The method [`getChildMeasureSpec`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec%28int%2Cint%2Cint%29) is to blame. Essentially, both children are measured with the full width and then draw one on top of the other, in the order in which they appear in the layout. Changing `layout_width` to `wrap_content` will fix it but cause an unnecessary measure pass. `0dp` avoids that.

Comment: `fill_parent` or similarly `match_parent` (both do the same) are requesting the layout to exactly match the width of their parent. In that case, weights are like divisors for these widths. I do not know why. `0dp` means that by default the width is zero, and the weights serve to augment this size to fill all the layout.